# How to add column and row value from excel in list view with assets folder?

Tags: android, listview

I want to retrieve one excel file data in list view with images from assets folder, is that possible ?   please help me how can i?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider using something called JExcelApi. I have no experience with it. The formal Java API for Microsoft Documents is Apache POI but as far as I know it was not compatible with Android and the Dalvik VM in the past. Actually JExcelApi is the proven method for reading, writing and even creating excel documents. Check out this article:

[Using JExcelApi in an Android App](http://www.kylebeal.com/blog/2011/10/using-jexcelapi-in-an-android-app/)

Here is the official API website with api documentation and simple examples for the usage:

[Java Excel API - A Java API to read, write, and modify Excel spreadsheets](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Good luck!